# How can I load an external file/program in memory and then execute it (C++ and Unix)?

Tags: c++, unix, memory, execute

Let's say I have an executable file called "execfile". I want to read that file using a C++ program (on Unix) and then execute it from memory. I know this is possible on Windows but I was not able to find a solution for Unix.

In pseudo-code it would be something like this:

```
declare buffer (char *)
readfile "execfile" in buffer
execute buffer
```

Just to make it clear: obviously I could just execute the file using `system("execfile")`, but, as I said, this is not what I intend to do.

Thank you.

EDIT 1: To make it even more clear (and the reason why I can't use `dlopen`): the reason I need this functionality is because the executable files are going to be generated dynamically and so I cannot just build all of them at once in a single library. To be more precise I'm building a tool that will first encrypt an executable file with a key and then it will be able to execute that encrypted file, first decrypting it and then executing it (and I don't want to have a copy of the decrypted file on the file system).

Comment: Loading the executable in memory is the role of the OS. And even if you did it by hand, you wouldn't take into account 1. dynamic libraries, and 2. COW.

Comment: On Windows you have to use VirtualAlloc and manually create some pages with PAGE_EXECUTE access (since data pages aren't executable by default).  I presume you also have to do something like this on UNIX style OSes since non-executable heaps are the norm these days.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you trying to run dynamically generated native code?  That's the only reason I can imagine wanting to do this..

Comment: I just added an EDIT to my original question so you can see why I need this. I hope it's clear.

Comment: what about putting the file on /dev/shm (or any other ramdisk like area) and after execing it, unlink it?

Comment: Because during it's execution it will be readable and therefore it will be possible to obtain a copy of it.

Comment: Unfortunately I am afraid that it is impossible - if you don't want it in filesystem, it will not run. Anyway, why do you bother doing it this way? If you want to protect your program, just add some code to it that is exiting if run unauthorized. And if you are afraid of asm-hackers cuting it out, then remember that they can just as well hack your decrypting program.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot without writing a mountain of code. Loading and linking an a.out is a kernel facility, not a user mode facility, on linux.

You'd be better off making a shared library and loading it with `dlopen`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I need this is because the executable files are going to be generated dynamically and so I cannot just build all of them at once in a single library. To be more precise I'm building a tool that will first encrypt an executable file with a key and then it will be able to execute that encrypted file (and I don't want to have a copy of the decrypted file on the file system).

Comment: Don't build executables. Build .so files. You can then decrypt and load them.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that either. The scripts come as shell scripts and are provided by a 3rd party entity.

Comment: Shell scripts? So are you having executables or shell scripts? Running shell scripts in-memory sohuld be possible, provided that they don't call any other protected code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to load-and-run -- not necessarily in C++ -- is to use `dlopen`+`dlsym` to load dynamic library and obtain a pointer to function defined in the library.

See [C++ dlopen mini HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/) for description of solving problems with C++ symbols in dynamic libraries.